# Acer X480G shows invalid boot disk

Tags: lubuntu, acer

I have an old Acer Veriton X480G pc.  I'm trying to install Lubuntu on it, but keep getting "Invalid System Disk" error.  I have the pc's 1st boot device set to Removable Disk, Legacy Boot set to Enabled.  Hit F12 for Boot Menu but I keep getting the error.  I have formatted the usb drive to Fat32 and wrote to iso to usb using PowerISO.  I am not trying to dual boot, just want to install it on a Toshiba 1tb sata drive.

I'll try changing the HD to another I have and try a different linux boot.  I have a few on usb.

Update: I can boot from win10 on the same type of usb drive and can also boot from my Linux Mint usb drive.  Just cannot boot from any of my ubuntu usb drives.  They were all created with the latest downloads on PowerISO.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.
JP

Comment: Details are somewhat vague, you mention Lubuntu, but have provided no clues as to which Lubuntu release & ISO you're trying to install. You also don't give any clues as to what you actually achieve (ie. are you booting & installing & the system won't boot after installation? or something else?).  You also mention formatting the USB; if the ISO is written as documented for Ubuntu/Lubuntu, any format option is erased, with format only relevant if you're *reformatting* the ISO to *non-standard*; why not try the documented *standard* approach?  (the ISO is *cloned* to install media)

Comment: Sorry for being so vague....  It's Lubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso LTS Jammy Jelly Fish downlowded from Lubuntu's website.  I quote from my original question: "I'm trying to install Lubuntu on it, but keep getting "Invalid System Disk" error." This is the INITIAL boot to install it.  And No I have not and never have "reformatted the iso".  I've always followed the standard approach.  I've done this a million times on many pc's and laptops.  If you notice the Update in my initial question, I can install linux mint and win10, just not any ubuntu flavors.

Comment: Is your PowerISO capable of writing the *modern* Ubuntu ISOs?  as they differ for releases past 20.04 & updated software is required where the ISO is reformatted during write (ie. you do **not** format an ISO using ISO writing software **except** when reformating it, as a *burn* or *clone* of ISO to media will cause a new partition table to be obtained from the ISO itself & thus any formatting is lost; your text implies you're reformatting the ISO by options during write; Linux Mint differs to (modern) Ubuntu ISOs as all architectures boot the same way; Mint only write for *amd64*)

Comment: Ahh! ok, I just did an update of PowerISO to the latest version.  Seems like I was a couple of versions behind.  Anyway, I updated the software and created a new bootable usb with the Lubuntu iso and it's booting correctly now.  Thanks, man.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question then (*I've never used PowerISO, thus you're likely able to write an answer better than I could*).  After writing it (*and however long the site requires you to allow others to write alternative answers*) you can accept it & gain some rep.  You can refer to me if you wish.. (*Ubuntu ISOs differ from 20.10 & later, when contrasted with 20.04 & earlier as Ubuntu strives for all architectures to boot the same for any given release now; ie. amd64, armhf, arm64, ppc64el, s390x, riscv64 etc all boot the same for yy.mm release*)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to guiverc I was able to figure out that the software I use to create my bootable usb's (PowerISO) was a couple of versions out of date.  When guiverc mentioned that the Ubuntu ISOs have changed and asked if my software was up to date, I checked and needed to upgrade to the most current Version of PowerISO.  Then I created a new bootable usb and it booted correctly and did not give me the "Invalid System disk" error.

Thanks again guiverc.
John Paul